# Python logging from an url into a text file

Tags: python, url, logging, text, handlers

I'm trying to logging text from this URL site: http://radio.nolife-radio.com:8000/played.html
into a text file. I've decided to try using the Python Logging module. So far I got nothing, I have been reading some here: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/logging.html Not sure if I should use the SocketHandler or HTTPHandler. I'm quite new to this and still looking through the tutorials. There might be an easier solution using Urllib or something I don't know. The URL site is a radio station and is updated after each track. I want the updated information to be logged. Here is the progress so far:

```
import logging, logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger('Radio Station')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh = logging.FileHandler('thread.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
host = 'localhost:8000'
url = 'www.radio.nolife-radio.com:8000/played.html'
http_handler = logging.handlers.HTTPHandler(host, url, method='GET')
logger.addHandler(http_handler)
logger.info("")
```

The code above doesn't work at the moment. If I remove the HTTP code, this is the outcome:

```
2013-11-11 00:22:19,640 - Radio Station - INFO -
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to fetch the URL and write the contents down into a file?

Comment: I think it might be a question of mistaken terms.. `Logging` is more for logging the activity within your program.  You should be able to do this with `urllib`: `urllib.urlopen("http://radio.nolife-radio.com:8000/played.html").read()`

Comment: That would be great. Something like that, yes.

Comment: If you're on linux, you could use curl from the command line.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 OS, I will try to use urllib and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

OK, a quick example here with [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) that should be fine on Windows, you will have to solve the problem of what to do with the HTML you get (I recommend that you use the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module for parsing HTML).

```
from urllib import FancyURLopener

page_url = "http://radio.nolife-radio.com:8000/played.html"

class myUrlOpener( FancyURLopener ):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11"

opener = myUrlOpener()

page_contents = opener.open( page_url ).read()

print page_contents
```

This may be a little more complicated than the basic examples you will find on the internet, as this site doesn't seem to accept requests from the Python urllib User Agent.  Here, by invoking `FancyURLopener` we can set the User Agent to be that of Firefox on Windows.

**Check that site's (*nolife-radio.com*) policy regarding the scraping of content from their pages.**